# Improve SQL Server query performance with table having medium data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, query-performance

I have a table with 6000 records but it could be larger in the future. I have attached screen dump of my current SQL query which takes 12 to 14 seconds to load 6000 rows of data.

There are already indexes on the columns which are queried most commonly

How can I improve query performance or modify query for the same?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  (
     [Srno]          [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [ITEMCode]      [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
     [BranchId]      [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
     [ITEM_No]       [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
     [ITEM_Desc]     [VARCHAR](200) NULL,
     [DeptId]        [BIGINT] NULL,
     [CatId]         [BIGINT] NULL,
     [SizeId]        [BIGINT] NULL,
     [CostPrice]     [DECIMAL](18, 3) NULL,
     [SalesPrice]    [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
     [ITEM_InStock]  [BIGINT] NULL,
     [UserId]        [BIGINT] NULL,
     [Active]        [BIT] NOT NULL,
     [IsDeleted]     [BIT] NOT NULL,
     [Quantity]      [INT] NULL,
     [IsFavourite]   [BIT] NULL,
     [IsProductLink] [BIT] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Item_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ITEMCode] ASC, [BranchId] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  )
ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_Item] FOREIGN KEY([ITEMCode], [BranchId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Item] ([ITEMCode], [BranchId])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_Item]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_ITEM_UnitPrice] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CostPrice]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_ITEM_RETAILPRICE] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SalesPrice]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_ITEM_InStock] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ITEM_InStock]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_Active] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Active]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Item_DelFlag] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]

GO
```

I have updated query and removed join of Department table but still it takes **10 Seconds**

```
   SELECT Item.ITEMCode                 AS ItemId,
       ISNULL(Item.ITEM_No, '0')     AS ItemNo,
       isnull(Item.Barcode, '')      AS Barcode,
       Item.ITEM_Desc                AS ItemName,
       isnull(item_Imagepath, '')    AS ItemImage,
       0                             AS availableQty,
       Item.SalesPrice               AS Price,
       isnull(Item.TaxApply, 0)      AS isTax,
       Item.TaxType,
       ISNULL(Item.ITM_Type, '0')    AS ITMType,
       Item.Profit_Type              AS ProfitType,
       Item.Profit_Amt               AS ProfitAmt,
       Item.CostPrice,
       ISNULL(Item.ITEM_Remarks, '') AS Remark
FROM   Item
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your query **as SQL text** (instead of a screenshot)! And please also post your table structure and the **exact index definitions** so that we know what we're looking at here....

Comment: How many rows in `Department`? How many rows in `Item`? What is the estimated and actual rows coming out of `Department`? 12 to 14 seconds looks pretty slow for that plan unless the tables are huge. What wait types is the query getting?

Comment: I hate `distinct` :) It cost's and most of the time it is used the conditions are not good enough. Maybe you could do some refactoring and remove `distinct`?

Comment: Tipp: use `WHERE 1=1` so you can always add a new condition beginning with `AND ...` ;)

Comment: Total Rows in Item - 6016, Total rows in Department - 15

Comment: I have tried by removing distinct and where condition but still same , it takes 12 seconds

Comment: So 12-14 seconds to process 6031 rows is very slow! Are there any computed columns calling Scalar UDFs in there? When you execute the query look in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` from another connection and see what wait types are shown for that session.

Comment: it says invalid object name "sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks" when i try exec sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks

Comment: Btw, I am using Azure Sql Database

Comment: It  is a view not a procedure so you `SELECT` from it. I have no idea if it is available on Azure.

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up between Item and Department? Is Department indexed? Do you need to perform the join on 2 columns, is BranchId not unique?

Comment: sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks is not available in Sql Azure

Comment: Table - Department - BranchId and DeptId Composite Primary Key and in Item DeptId is Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

If it takes 10 seconds to read 6000 (small) records then I can only assume/hope that your connection is introducing a lot of delays here!?!

Could you try the following and see how long this takes?

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT * INTO #test FROM [Item]
```

If this runs quickly then I'd go look for ways to speed up your connection between your computer and the Azure severs. (network packet size?)

Comment: LOL, only just noticed this Q dates back from Jan '14 =)